# SQL Server Join issue / alternate ways

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a query which I am trying to find out chain relationship between customer id. Currently 80k records are taking approx. 7 minutes. Could you please suggest some alternate improved ways?

Sample format is shown below. Here we are grouping based on records having  relationships among them (a = b = c)

```
Create table #chaintable
(
    CustID int, 
    MatchCustID int, 
    FN varchar(10), 
    LN varchar(10), 
    PhoneNo int, 
    Email varchar(50), 
    dtAppointment int
)

insert into #chaintable
Select 1,2,'Global','Chain',123,'',1
union all
Select 2,3,'Global','Chain',123,'a@a.com',2
union all
Select 3,2,'Global','Chain',567,'a@a.com',3
union all
Select 4,5,'Global1','Chain1',123,'a@a.com',1
union all
Select 5,4,'Global1','Chain1',123,'a@a.com',2

Select distinct 
    A.CustID, A.MatchCustID, A.GroupID  
from 
    (select 
         c1.CustID, c1.MatchCustID, C1.dtAppointment,
         case 
            when C1.CustID = C2.MatchCustID and C1.MatchCustID <> C2.CustID 
               then C1.CustID
            when C1.CustID <> C2.MatchCustID and C1.MatchCustID = C2.CustID 
               then c1.MatchCustID
            when C1.CustID = C2.MatchCustID and C1.MatchCustID = C2.CustID 
               then 
                  case 
                     when c1.CustID < C1.MatchCustID 
                        then c1.CustID
                        else c1.MatchCustID
                  end
         end GroupID
     from 
         #chaintable C1, #chaintable C2
     where 
         c1.CustID = c2.MatchCustID 
         or c1.MatchCustID = c2.CustID) A
```

Output:

```
CustID  MatchCustID FN  LN  PhoneNo Email   dtAppointment
---------------------------------------------------------    
    1   2   Global  Chain   123         1

    2   3   Global  Chain   123 a@a.com 2

    3   2   Global  Chain   567 a@a.com 3
    4   5   Global1 Chain1  123 a@a.com 1
    5   4   Global1 Chain1  123 a@a.com 2
```

Comment: @DVT Execution plan will be the same. It won't help

Comment: Why use the UNION ALL at all? Just do it proper: INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> (COL_1, COL_2) VALUES (<your columns >), (<your columns>),etc

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

First, it is impossible to help improve performance of a query without knowing the execution plan.

There are certain problem here that I do not understand. Example, why do you have a join to the table itself and all of the outputs are values of the first table. Is the join really necessary? Or is it just for the sake of testing?

I suggest the below "logically equivalent" way of rewriting the query without using the `OR` in the JOIN and less work to understand the query to human (and if the computer feel the same, then it might improve).

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.CustID, c1.MatchCustID,
CASE WHEN (C1.MatchCustID <> c2.CustID) 
       OR (c1.CustID < c1.MatchCustID) THEN c1.CustID
     ELSE c1.MatchCustID END AS GroupID
FROM #chaintable C1 JOIN  #chaintable C2
ON c1.CustID = c2.MatchCustID

UNION

SELECT c1.CustID, c1.MatchCustID,
   c1.MatchCustID AS GroupID
FROM #chaintable C1 JOIN  #chaintable C2
ON c2.CustID = c1.MatchCustID AND C1.CustID<>C2.MatchCustID
```

Comment: Cost of query from question = 25%. Cost of your query = 75%. Please see  Execution plan. This not improve performance definitely :)

Comment: @MegaTron Do you have the execution plan of the 80k records version? If yes, can you post it?

Comment: It doesn't metter. Look at operation that exucute when you use union. Union make multiple table scan and hash match

Comment: @MegaTron Did you see the SELECT DISTINCT of the outer query in the OP post? It is also a `SORT`.

Comment: So if you have such bad cost on a few data then why do you think it will be good for 80k records

Comment: The number of records matter. The query plan change depends on it. As I said in the post, I did not say it will **definitely** make improvement (the OP did not post the plan). I just suggested a way to write it in an easier manner to read.

Comment: But question was about performance not about manner to write, wasn't it?

Comment: @MegaTron I'll let the OP decide it.

Comment: UNION forces the optimizer to combine the rows uniquely...meaning those extra work in your query plan. In contrast, UNION ALL joins the tables without regard to duplicates.

Comment: @clifton_h But I removed the SELECT DISTINCT of the outer statement. That is the trade off I was looking for in this case.

Comment: Again, you misunderstand how the operator works. [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) combines tables and REMOVES duplicates. Therefore it enforces its own distinct operation. You can see an example of this on Dave Pinal's [Difference Between Union vs. Union All](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/)

Answer (score 0):

First, try to stick to the standard when adding rows to a table. While `UNION ALL` may be efficient enough to handle your simple rows, it seems rather verbose for a large set of inserts like you mentioned. However you do this, make sure you treat them as sets of relational data and avoid unnecessary steps.

Furthermore, `CARTESIAN JOIN` is old SQL syntax, today's `OUTER` and `INNER JOIN`s more proficient, and as such this old style of join is only really useful in niche cases. This not being one of them.

Looking at your table and the results, the following about your table structure are observed:

- CustID is independent of this table.
- MatchCustID has no barring on the order
- Appointment is the durable Key.
- FN and LN together form an ID that dictates the GROUPID

So then, a solution may be as follows:

```
Create table #chaintable
(
    CustID int, MatchCustID int, FN varchar(10), LN varchar(10)
  , PhoneNo, Email varchar(50), dtAppointment int
) 

INSERT INTO #chaintable
VALUES (1,2,'Global','Chain',123,'',1)
     , (2,3,'Global','Chain',123,'a@a.com',2)
     , (3,2,'Global','Chain',567,'a@a.com',3)
     , (4,5,'Global1','Chain1',123,'a@a.com',1)
     , (5,4,'Global1','Chain1',123,'a@a.com',2)

SELECT CustID
      ,MatchCustID
      ,dtAppointment
      , FN
      , LN
      , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY FN + LN DESC ) AS GroupID
FROM #chaintable
```

Resuls:

```
CustID  MatchCustID dtAppointment     FN       LN   GroupID
1               2         1         Global    Chain     1
2               3         2         Global    Chain     1
3               2         3         Global    Chain     1
4               5         1         Global1   Chain1    2
5               4         2         Global1   Chain1    2
```

The only catch here is how the unique ID was used. In this example, since I have no value that uniquely identifies the event chains, I used FN + LN to bring back an order.

This has several advantages:

1. You avoid costly `Cartesian JOIN`s by passing through your rows once.
2. `GROUPID` Will always be the same for each group in your final table.
3. Performing prechecks will not be difficult:

> ```
> DECLARE @GROUPID = (SELECT MAX(GROUPID) FROM <SourceTable> )
> ```

However, this also has drawbacks:

- Adding to this table may require you break up the insert statements to check for existing GROUPIDs (which sadly your data does not already have). Which in your case, the columns that determines GROUPID is FN + LN.
- I would suggest a temp table that grabs the unique FN + LN values and then runs an outer apply operation such as

Example

```
SELECT FN + LN FROM #chaintable A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM #chaintable
                  WHERE A.FN = FN
                    AND A.LN = LN)
```

Before running an insert statement that adds the pre-value we checked earlier in the insert statement:

```
DECLARE @GROUPID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(GROUPID), 0) FROM <SourceTable> )
INSERT INTO FINAL_TABLE (CustID, MatchCustID, FN, LN, PhoneNo, Email, dtAppointment)
SELECT  CustID
      , MatchCustID
      , FN
      , LN
      , PhoneNo
      , Email
      , dtAppointment
      , @GROUPID + DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY FN + LN DESC ) AS GroupID
FROM #chaintable_sub
```

This will always result in the next GROUPID being of greater number than the previous entries.

Finally, I would advise you treat this data as it really is: `Dirty Data`. You have to perform `ETL` transformations on it, particularly since you have a durable key with a composite ID key...so essentially a FACT table.

Comment: Please note there are many ways to accomplish this, so be sure to test the different methods. Note that Operators are meant for LARGE amounts of data between the tables.

Hopefully, I gave you some insight into how to proceed with your ETL process. Regards,